# &owner for posting new model doesn't work

Tags: loopbackjs, acl, loopback

Using this ACL for models, I want to prevent creating new models that have owner (userId) for those access-tokens that lead to other users, rather than the actual owner. I don't want userId 4 post a new model, and set that model's owners to 5, another userId. But this doesn't work right now, since there is no model on database to check, so what should I do? This worked for deletion last time I checked. But I need for posting...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.

`server/boot/01-add-user.js`

```
module.exports = (server) => {

  // Before each create request, assign the userId property to the userId of the accessToken

  const addUser = async (ctx) => {

    function assignUserId(o) {
      o.userId = ctx.req.accessToken.userId;
    }
    // You can post arrays of objects to loopback
    if (Array.isArray(ctx.req.body)){
      ctx.req.body.forEach(assignUserId);
    } else {
      assignUserId(ctx.req.body);
    }
  };

  server.models.MY_MODEL.beforeRemote('create', addUser);
}
```

For your ACLs try this

```
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: I tested but it didn't work. Just o clarify, my model's userId name is owner. So I changed ctc.req.body.owner. And in loopback, I first deny all methods for Write of my model for all users, then give owners access for Write of my model

Comment: "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],

Comment: You wont be able to restrict access based on $owner on something which does not exists.  The above `beforeRemote` simply makes it so that no matter what the user `creates, its userId/owner always comes from their accessToken.   I added ACLs which might help you.

Comment: Thank you Marvin it worked. Now since you're here, I have another question pleaseeeee. So theses ACL roles say no one can do anything, but owner can write and read. The last one says only autenticated users can create? is that it?

Comment: Exactly correct.  I've also editing my answer to handle an array in the request body

Comment: Thanks for the array feature. Just wondering, are those codes nodejs? I literally didn't have an idea how to write these codes and extend the loopback in the way I want! Where can I learn more to do things like these? is it loopback related or just generic nodejs?

Comment: In loopback 2&3, whatever javascript you put into `server/boot` will be executed and given the `server` parameter (sometimes called `app`).  Here you can access `server.datasources.MY_DATASOURCE` and `server.models.MY_MODEL` and do all sorts of fun things.   https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Adding-logic-to-models.html is a nice place to start